# Laravel AJAX Bootstrap Toggle Switch doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, bootstrap-switch

I'm currently working on a Laravel project. In the admin view I got Bootstrap Toggle for activating/deactivating users. Everything works well besides the fact that I can't change the checkboxes into a Toggle. When i change class="toggle-class" into data-toggle="toggle", The toggle appears but the data won't be send to the database anymore so the code won't work anymore...

[image]

This is what I have

[image]

This is what I want

My Admin view

```
    <input id="{{$user->id}}" class="toggle-class" 
                            type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" 
                            data-on="Active" data-off="Inactive" 
                            {{ $user->status ? 'checked' : '' }}
                            onclick="changeStatus(event.target, {{ $user->id }});">
    


    function changeStatus(_this, id) {
    var status = $(_this).prop('checked') == true ? 1 : 0;
    let _token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

    $.ajax({
        url: '{{route("change.status")}}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            _token: _token,
            id: id,
            status: status 
        },
        success: function(data){
            if (data.type == "error") {
                $('#message').html("<div class='alert alert-danger card h2'>"+data.fail+"</div>");} 
                else {
                    $('#message').html("<div class='alert alert-success card h2'>"+data.success+" 
        </div>");
}}
    });
}
```

The method in my controller

```
public function changeStatus(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::find($request->id);
    $user->status = $request->status;
    $user->save();

    return response()->json(['success'=>'Status change successfully.']);
}
```

Don't know what I'm doing wrong tbh. Can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: If input unchecked, then that won't be send with Request.

Comment: Tried that too, nothing changes

Comment: What you have gotten on the `dd($request->all());`? While checked and unchecked

Comment: I haven't implemented dd($request->all()); in my code, it was never needed

Comment: I know, dd is for debugging.  I just want to see what you get on the request

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem as you by replacing the places of inactive and active my problems get solved.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDNJY.png)

> ```
> var status = $(this).children().prop('checked') == true ? 'active' : 'inactive';
> ```

to this line

> ```
> var status = $(this).children().prop('checked') == true ? 'inactive' : 'active';
> ```

here is my code

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
      var status = $(this).children().prop('checked') == true ? 'inactive' : 'active';
      var id = $(this).children().data('id');
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'statusUpdate',
        data: {
          'status': status,
          'id': id
        },
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        },
        success: function(data) {
          Swal.fire(
            'GREAT!', 'Status changed successfully', 'success')
          location.reload();
          console.log(data.success);
        }
      });
    });
  }) <
  /script>
```

```html
<input data-id="{{ $catego->id }}" class="toggle-class" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="Inactive" data-onstyle="warning" data-offstyle="dark" type="checkbox" {{ $catego->status == 'active' ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

> route code//    Route::post('statusUpdate', [CategoryCRUDController::class, 'changeStatus']);

```html
// My controller 

public function changeStatus(Request $request) { 
$category = Category::find($request->id);
$category->status = $request->status; 
$category->save(); 

return response()->json(['success'=>' status change successfully.']); }
```

[the source code](https://github.com/Faeza97/laravel_crud)